# Problem with one command I want to execute through Java in Linux shell

Tags: java, linux

I'm currently working on a Plugin which also can execute commands in the Linux shell. I've setup some commands that I will need later. Killing screens is already working but now I want to start some screen's through my Plugin. But this isn't working.

I've tried to change from `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);` to a ProcessBuilder worked for killing screens.

My method to execute commands

```java
public static void shellExecuteBuilder(String[] command, Player p, boolean bool, String Wrapper) {

        ProcessBuilder prb;

        try {
            prb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            prb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process pro = prb.start();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while (prb.redirectErrorStream() == true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            if (bool == true) {
                p.sendMessage("§aDer Wrapper §e" + Wrapper + " §awurde angehalten!");
            } else {
                p.sendMessage("§aDer Wrapper §e" + Wrapper + " §awurde gestartet!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (bool == true) {
                p.sendMessage("§cDer Wrapper §e" + Wrapper + " §ckonnte nicht angehalten werden!");
            } else {
                p.sendMessage("§cDer Wrapper §e" + Wrapper + " §ckonnte nicht gestartet werden!");
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

How I setup this in another method

```java
String[] command = new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /path/to/my/script/", "./start.sh"};

shellExecuteBuilder(command, p, false, Wrapper);
```

I expected that my method will startup a new screen but it actually does not do anything.

Comment: unrelated: "== true" is bad style. Just use if (someBoolean). And: "bool" isn't a helpful name for a variable. Use a name that **says** what the variable is about, not what type it has.

Comment: Well I think you're right, but this way is working so far. And im still pretty new to Java I just started last year in November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/sh` can accept a sequence of commands, but formatted differently than you have it. Try this instead:

```
String[] command = new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /path/to/my/script/; ./start.sh"};
```

Also, the way you process the output from the process will never end.  The `while` loop should be testing the returned output from the process, not the redirection setting (which will never change).  Here's a modified version that properly reads the output and wait for the subshell to exit.  Note that I removed some of your app's variables (`bool`, `Wrapper`, `Player`) to simplify the example:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class TestPB {

    public static void shellExecuteBuilder(String[] command) {

        ProcessBuilder prb;

        try {
            prb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            prb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process pro = prb.start();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while( (line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            pro.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        TestPB tpb = new TestPB();
        String[] command = new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /path/to/my/script/; ./start.sh"};
        TestPB.shellExecuteBuilder(command);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of telling the shell to change directory `ProcessBuilder` can do it, although not with the way you currently have your program 'factored':

```
 ProcessBuilder prb = new ProcessBuilder ("/bin/sh", "-c", "./startsh");
 prb.directory("/path/to/my/script");
 prb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 Process pro = prb.start();
```

or using 'fluent' style all in one statement:

```
Process pro = new ProcessBuilder ("/bin/sh", "-c", "./startsh")
    .directory("/path/to/my/script").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
```